# Defining secondary function in where

Tags: haskell, where-clause

I have this which works

```
import Data.List
import Data.Maybe

mI l n | l == [] = Nothing
       | n == 0 = Just h
       | otherwise = mI t (n-1)
  where h = head l
        t = tail l
```

and then this, which successfully allows me to get a number value out of `Just`

```
myIndex l n
  | m == Nothing = error "No list."
  | otherwise = fromJust m 
      where m = mI l n
```

And yet I can't do this without an error

```
myIndex' l n
  | m == Nothing = error "No list."
  | otherwise = fromJust m
      where m = mI l n | l == [] = Nothing
                       | n == 0 = Just h
                       | otherwise = mI t (n-1)
                   where h = head l
                         t = tail l
```

...

```
error: parse error on input `|'
```

Why won't it allow me to define the secondary function within the second `where`?

Comment: What is the nested definition even trying to do? The problem is not the nesting; it’s the fact that you’re doing `m = mI l n` and _then_ a guard.

Comment: I see. But then I can't see how to get just the functionality of `mI` after `where m...`

Comment: What exactly do you mean by ‘getting the functionality of `mI`’?

Comment: Getting the right answer into `m`.

Comment: I’m really sorry, I’m just struggling to understand exactly what you’re trying to do. Are you trying to run `mI l n`, then assign the result to `m`? If so, then why do you need the guards?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to cram the definitions of both `m` and `mI` into one definition.

What you probably meant to do what this:

```
myIndex' l n
  | m == Nothing = error "No list."
  | otherwise = fromJust m
      where m = mI l n
            mI l n | l == [] = Nothing
                   | n == 0 = Just h
                   | otherwise = mI t (n-1)
                   where h = head l
                         t = tail l
```

Comment: Yes, just saw that. Or I could just define `mI` directly after the `where` and replace the `m`s with `(mI l n). That works too, but your suggestion is easier to see and follow.

Answer (score 3):

Your line

```hs
  where m = mI l n ...
```

doesn't make sense.  Are you defining `m` or are you defining a function `mI`?  I think what you want is:

```hs
  where m = mI l n
        mI l n | l == ...
```

---

Also, it would be better to use patterns, e.g.

```hs
mI [] n = Nothing
mI (h:t) n | n == 0 = Just h
           | otherwise = mI t (n-1)
```